# kubectl apply results in ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubectl

I'm getting the following error on `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/pods/simple-pod.yaml`

`Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 17s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx:1.14.2": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:1.14.2": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/nginx:1.14.2": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/1.14.2": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I've added all the root CA to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` on Ubuntu, yet the above `kubectl` command is stil failing. Is there any specfic location `kubectl` looks for the root CA certs ?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Okay, I got confused, it is basically my worker nodes that can't pull the image, not my local environment ... so basically I need to find a way to insert the root CA in every worker node. But still, wondering, why did the install of AKS not fail in the first place ...

Comment: Does your network have a proxy? You should not need to manually alter certificate stores to contact public internet sites.

Comment: Yes, it does. There is Palo Alto in the path and since I'm deploying the cluster in outboundType mode set to userDefinedRouting ALL traffic from the AKS subnet should go via the hub where the PA's are located. So I can understand that since the PA is performing  MITM that I would have to provide the root CA of the PA so that it can verify the signature on the certificate, but why did the installation of AKS  work in first place (since it is still behing the PA's and I did not specify the root CA for the PA in any place) I have no idea.